# How use other variables in other classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this phone book program that takes a phone number and the type of phone number (it can be your home phone, cell phone, etc.) which is referred to as label. The program can take those values and store it in an address book where it can add contacts, delete contacts, and find a contact.

There is a class called PhoneContact that uses two parameters: phone number and label. The purpose of this class is to take in a phone number along with a label(Home phone, work phone, cell phone, etc.) and returns the output of what type of phone number it is, what the area code of that number is, etc.

An example would be:

```
James_May = PhoneContact.new('(555) 555-5555', :mobile)
puts James_May.phone_number
>> (555) 555-555
puts James_May.label
>> mobile
```

I created a PhoneBook class that is able to store, add, delete, and find phone contacts.

An Example of this is:

```
 JG_contact = PhoneBook.new
    JG_contact.add('Gary, James', '5555555555', :home)
    puts "** JG's new entry:"
    >> **James's new entry:
    puts book.find('Gary, James')
    >>(954) 111-2222 (work)
      (444) 555-5555 (cell)
```

*My problem is I'm not sure how to implement the variables like    phone_number and label from the PhoneNumber class to the PhoneBook    class. How do I use variables from other classes and does it make    sense to implement these variables in a hash?*

Here is a snippet of the code from the PhoneClass:

```
class PhoneContact
  attr_reader :label

  def initialize(phone_number, label)
    @label = label
    @phone_number = normalize(phone_number)
  end
```

Here is the code from the PhoneBook Class:

```
require_relative ./PhoneContact

    class PhoneBook

      def contactList
        @contactList ||= {}
      end

      def add_contact (newContact = {})
        flag = false
        if newContact.length < 1
          return flag
        else
          flag = true
          newContact.collect do |name, number|
            contactList[name] = number
          end
          return flag
        end
      end

      def delete (targetName)
        if !contactList.has_key?(targetName)
          return false
        else
          contactList.delete(targetName)
          return true
        end

      end
      def display_contact (targetName)
        number = -1
        if contactList.has_key?(targetName)
          number = contactList(targetName)
          puts "Contact name : #{targetName}, Contact Number, #{number}"
        else
          puts "#{targetName} doesn't exist in the phonebook"
        end
      end

      def display_all_contacts
        if !contactList.empty?
          contactList.each {|name, number| puts "Contact name: #{name}, contact number #{number}" }
      else
        puts "You don't have any contact details your phonebook"
      end
      end
      end
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Let's say class `A` has attributes `b` and `c` (that are readable). Let's say `a` is of type `A`. If you want to access `b` or `c` you can just run `a.b` and `a.c` respectively.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out two things. First, how can you use phone_number and label from the PhoneContact class? As you said, can I do Phonebook.phone_number and PhoneBook.label to call those variables? Secondly, How do I make my add method work? I want the add method to use the parameters: name, phone_number, and label. So, when I use the method find(name) it will show the name.

Comment: You can't call `Phonebook.phone_number` as `Phonebook` is the class. You need to call it on an instance variable of type `Phonebook`. You can do this `pb = Phonebook.new`, then `pb.phone_number` or `pb.label`.

Comment: I see. and for my add method  can I do something like this `def add_contact (newContact = {})
        flag = false
        if newContact.length < 1
          return flag
        else
          flag = true
          newContact.collect do |pb.name, pb.phone_number, pb.label|
            contactList[name] = number
          end
          return flag
        end
      end`

Comment: Try to avoid doing double-negative conditions. You have `if !contactList` and it has an `else` clause, which means the second case is `if !!contactList`. Try inverting the logic and swapping the blocks. Additionally Ruby strongly encourages the `contact_list` style naming convention for methods and variables, all lower-case.

Comment: Your add function is wrong. You defined it with param (a hash) but you're calling it with three params (name, phone_number, label). Your code does not correspond to the example. I would first start by creating a hash in your add function that instantiates a PhoneContact object. Once you do that add it to your hash, then add the logic in your add method. Also, you may need an initialize method in your PhoneBook that creates a global hash or an instance variable hash. Break down your code one method at a time. Right now, your code is useless according to your example.

Comment: Your PhoneContact class needs to instantiate an object of PhoneNumber, not call the normalize method (not sure what you're doing here). Also, your phoneBook class has no find method, but you're using a find method in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so your confusion seems to be two-fold. The first problem is what object to call a method on. Let me provide you an explanation here. Say I have this class `A`

```
class A
  attr_accessor :b, :c

  def initialize(b, c)
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end

  class << self
    def alphabet
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    end
  end
end
```

Also, let's say I have `a = A.new('b', 8)`. I can call the methods I defined like this:

```
a.b # => 'b'
a.c # => 8
A.alphabet # => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

This works like this because `b` and `c` are instance methods which means they are called on an instance variable. `a` is an instance of the class `A`. However, `alphabet` is a class method (as evident by its being inside the `class << self` class), so that is called on the class itself. This should explain instance methods vs. class methods

Second problem: how do I write a `find` method for the phonebook class. So Phonebook has an attribute `contactList` and all of the elements in that array should be of the type `Phonecontact`, so to find a person from `contactList` by name we can do this

```
def find(name)
  @contactList.select {|i| i.name == name}
end
```

This will return an array of people with the name specified. If you want that array to be of their phone numbers you can do something like this. (Assume `pb` is a `Phonebook` with a contact list)

```
pb.find('james').map(&:phone_number)
```

Additionally, I recommend that your `add` method store `PhoneContacts`, so it can really be as simple as this

```
def add(contact)
  @contactList << contact
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It does clear things up. I now do understand what instance variables and instance methods are. I'm not sure if my question is clear my issue is how do I make a add method with the parameters label and phone_number from the PhoneContact class in the PhoneNumber class. 

I get that If I create a new instance of PhoneBook by doing `B = PhoneBook.new` But, I don't follow how `B.add('555-555-5555', :label)` is suppose to work when the add method can't use label and phone_number from the other class.

Comment: What is `:label` supposed to be referring to? If I have `james_may = PhoneContact.new('(555) 555-5555', :mobile)` and `b = PhoneBook.new` and I wanted to add `james_may` to `b`, I could do, `b.add(james_may.phone_number, james_may.label)`.

Comment: label refers to to what kind of phone number it is. So, it can be the person's home number, cell number, work number, etc. How would my add method in my PhoneBook class look if I'm doing this `b.add(james_may.phone_number, james_may.label)`? Because the way I was thinking was doing a hash. So, contact name would be with the phone number of the person.

Comment: Well you can change your add method to just take `james_may`. It would be better to store `PhoneContacts` instead of fields of `PhoneContacts`.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you what `add` should do.

Comment: I get an error: `in add': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Yes, because now in add you should do this instead `b.add(james_may)`.

Comment: I see, but I get this error now: ` `add': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)``

Comment: In `initialize` do `@contactList = []`. You don't want a hash. It doesn't make sense here.

Comment: So, something like this: `def initialize (contactList)
   @contactList =[ ]
  end` gives an error of `in initialize: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: You don't need `contactList` as a parameter for initialize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127225/discussion-between-eli-sadoff-and-codes316).

Comment: @Codes316 it gives you an error because when you're instantiating the object you need to pass in a parameter (in this case contactList) - but your example shows that you don't need to, instead you should create a phonecontact object in your add method and store it as a hash by name; also you can store a hash within your hash with label and phone number for a particular name. This would be the best approach.